# Java Properties.load() - how to switch key value pairs?

Tags: java, properties

I need to read in a Properties object from a file, however I need to switch the key and value pairs around, i.e. I need the keys to become the property values and vice-versa. I also cannot just change this on the file I am reading in. Any ideas how I could do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code please? i.e. [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: `code`Properties prop = new Properties();
  try {
   prop.load(newFileInputStream("/etc/file.types"));}

But I need to swap values round as I'm reading the file

Comment: Urgh no, don't make it a comment, edit it into your original question

Comment: Doesn't matter guy below posted a great answer

Comment: It does matter. Perhaps not for you but others who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a second `Properties` object, iterate over the entires you have just read, calling `put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey())` and you have it.

Comment: How do I iterate over the properties object?

Comment: Iterate over the `entrySet()`.

Answer (score -1):

Look for this [Properties.store()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: He wanted to know how to flip the values and he thought he cannot write to the same file he is reading from. The store will give him an ability to store the properties.

Comment: Yes, but that will store the properties in the same key-value arrangement rather than flip the values and keys...

Comment: Yes. I think I missed to point out that you can write to the properties file. I missed the flip part. I assumed that flipping while writing would do it.